# Adding radio buttons in Devise's new registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, radio-button, radio-group

My Ruby on Rails app uses Devise for user authentication.  While I've had no trouble adding fields to the default signup form, I'm a novice and have had no luck with radio buttons.

Each `:user` is a `:teacher` or `:student` (the `user` table is self-joined, in fact, on that basis).  The current working signup therefore requires the person signing up to type out "student" or "teacher" in the "Position" text field.  Naturally, it's not user-friendly even if functional, so I'd like to replace that text field with two radio buttons.

What I've tried:

In the `users.rb` model, I've added a constant:

```
POSITIONS = [ 
  ["student", "Student"], 
  ["teacher", "Teacher] 
]
```

To `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` I changed the field code to:

```
    <div class="radio">
      <%= f.label :position, 'Position', :class => 'position-button' %><br />
      <div class="input-form">
        <%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:position, @positions_collection, :first, :last) %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And then I moved on to the controller.  To my knowledge, if Devise was not part of my app, I'd call on the `POSITIONS` constant in `users_controller.rb` thusly:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @positions_collection = User::POSITIONS
end
```

However, the automatically generated `users_controller.rb` with Devise starts with nothing in `def new` but instead seems to be relying on the custom methods at the file's bottom to handle new users:

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def resource_class
    User
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

So I started to experiment, beginning with simply adding `@positions_collection = User::POSITIONS` to `def new`.  Reloading the signup page returned the following error: "NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
[snip] where line #30 raised: undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass".  This error comes up over and over again no matter where I've tried sticking `@positions_collection = User::POSITIONS` in the controller, even in the custom methods and even trying it in combination with `@user = User.new`.

(Line 30 is referring to `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:position, @positions_collection, :first, :last) %>` in the view file, which suggests `@positions_collection` is the stumbling block, I'd wager.)

Does anyone have thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with nil class is because is not defined in "create" method:

`@positions_collection = User::POSITIONS`

The simplest solution is to remove this variable and use `User::POSITIONS` directly in view.

`<% User::POSITIONS.map...`

Comment: After reading your answer, I tried `@positions...` in `def create` with no luck by chance, so I moved on to your simple solution.  The tweaks of

`<% student_or_teacher = User::POSITIONS.map {|x| x}%>` and `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:position, student_or_teacher, :first, :last) %>`

do the trick flawlessly.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you use string column to store user type. Better option will be use integer column `position` and enum to represent role of user:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum position: [:student, :user]

  ...

end
```

Then in your form, you can map values from enum:

```
<%= f.select(:position, User.positions.keys.map {|position| [position.titleize,position]}) %>
```

It will be more clear solution.

Comment: I did notice that modifying the DB to `enum` the position would probably be part of the best solution.  My reply time notwithstanding, I'm trying to get this project to a minimum level of presentability asap, so I took the quicker solution (Igor's): my database structure is already vast.  If by chance modifying the user table at this point would mess with any of the other delicate work, it'd possibly take hours to fix.

That said, I will certainly try this solution once I get to refactoring, and I've upvoted this solution even if it doesn't show up (apparently I'm still too new).  Thx!